# clang - how to declare a static const int in header file?

Tags: c++11, static, clang, constants, one-definition-rule

Given the following template in a header file, and a couple of  specializations:

```
template<typename> class A {
        static const int value;
};

template<> const int A<int>::value = 1;
template<> const int A<long>::value = 2;
```

and building with clang-5, it results in errors for each source unit that included the file, all complaining about multiple definitions for `A<int>::value` and `A<long>::value`.

At first, I thought that maybe the template specializations needed to be put in a specific translation unit, but on checking the spec, this apparently should be allowed, because the value is a constant integer.

Am I doing something else wrong?

EDIT: if I move the definition into a single translation unit, then I can no longer use the value of `A<T>::value` in the context of a `const int` (eg, where its value is being used to calculate the value of another const assignment) , so the value really needs to be in a header.

Comment: Since you *define* the variables for the specializations you still need to put them in a single translation unit. The linker will be able to put it together.

Comment: That doesn't work if you need to use the value of the constant to calculate a value for another constant (which needs to know the values of all of the constants at the point where it is assigned, and that may not be in the same translation unit if I remove it from the header).

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you have to initialise it in the header. You can define `template<> const int A<int>::value = 1; template<> const int A<long>::value = A<int>::value + 1;` in your `.cpp` file. Am I missing something?

Comment: @cantordust I think the goal of the OP is to make the constants *compile-time* constants, so they can be used in contexts where compile-time constants can be used.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see. This was not quite obvious, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In c++11 you maybe can go that way:

```
template<typename> class B {
    public:
        static const int value = 1;
};

template<> class B<long> {
    public:
        static const int value = 2;
};

template<typename T> const int B<T>::value;
```

If you only want to specialize the value var, you can use CRTP for that.

From C++17 you can make your definition inline:

```
template<> inline const int A<int>::value = 1;
template<> inline const int A<long>::value = 2;
```

Also from c++17 you can remove the 'template const int B::value;' for constexpr:

```
template<typename> class C {
    public:
        static constexpr int value = 1;
};

template<> class C<long> {
    public:
        static constexpr int value = 2;
};

// no need anymore for: template<typename T> const int C<T>::value;
```

And another solution for c++11 can be to use a inline method instead of inline vars which are allowed from c++17:

```
template<typename T> class D { 
    public:
        static constexpr int GetVal() { return 0; }

        static const int value = GetVal();
};  

template <> inline constexpr int D<int>::GetVal() { return 1; }
template <> inline constexpr int D<long>::GetVal() { return 2; }

template< typename T>
const int D<T>::value;
```

In addition to your last edit:

To use your values also in other dependent definitions it seems to be the most readable version if you use the inline constexpr methods.

Edit: "Special" version for clang, because as OP tells us, clang complains with "specialization happening after instantiation". I don't know if clang or gcc is wrong in that place...

```
template<typename T> class D {
    public:
        static constexpr int GetVal();
        static const int value;
};


template <> inline constexpr int D<int>::GetVal() { return 1; }
template <> inline constexpr int D<long>::GetVal() { return 2; }

template <typename T> const int D<T>::value = D<T>::GetVal();

int main()
{
    std::cout << D<int>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << D<long>::value << std::endl;
}
```

I told already that CRTP is possible if not the complete class should be redefined. I checked the code on clang and it compiles without any warning or error, because OP comments that he did not understand how to use it:

```
template<typename> class E_Impl {
    public:
        static const int value = 1;
};

template<> class E_Impl<long> {
    public:
        static const int value = 2;
};

template<typename T> const int E_Impl<T>::value;

template < typename T>
class E : public E_Impl<T>
{
    // rest of class definition goes here and must not specialized
    // and the values can be used here!

    public:

        void Check()
        {
            std::cout << this->value << std::endl;
        }
};


int main()
{
    E<long>().Check();
    std::cout << E<long>::value << std::endl;
    E<int>().Check();
    std::cout << E<int>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @markt1964:  I told you already that you can use CRTP but I added also an example for you now. A clang compliant version of the specialisation for the GetVar method is already added.